# Cannot run Spyder because No module named 'PySide'

Tags: python, spyder

I wanted to try using Spyder IDE. I was reading this page on how to open and run Spyder: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

I typed the following commands as specified in the page:

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda update spyder
```

Both commands gave "# All requested packages already installed.".

I then typed spyder into my terminal (Mac):

```
Macs-MacBook:~ macuser$ spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 166, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 159, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in <module>
```

So, I tried to install PySide:

```
Macs-MacBook:~ macuser$ conda install PySide
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
  - pyside
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

What should I do to get up and running with Spyder?

Comment: Hi, I'm using anaconda. I'm new to python but the docs and various resources I've read over the past few days have consistently told me to not use pip while I have anaconda. Is this true?

Comment: try if below commands let me know if it works, which OS  you are using?
pip install msgpack
conda install qt=5.6 pyqt=5.6 sip=4.18

Comment: Thank you! This worked with the conda command option that you provided. How did you know to use ```conda install qt=5.6 pyqt=5.6 sip=4.18```?  It's pretty specific

Comment: please mark answer so that it will be useful for others. basically, you can execute below command to understand which specific version is installed on your machine.
conda list --show-channel-urls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try below commands let me know if it works.

```
 pip install msgpack
 conda install qt=5.6 pyqt=5.6 sip=4.18
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue is, and why this works?

Comment: You should be using conda to install msgpack, not pip

Answer (score 2):

While other solutions found on the web didn't work for me (such as the one above and using `$ pip install pyqt5`), I solved this by uninstalling and reinstalling Spyder via terminal, using pip.

---

```
$ pip uninstall spyder
...
```

---

```
$ pip install spyder
...
```

---

Not sure why, but it worked on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

Mr J.

I had the same problem as Doug Fir. I used these commands. I launched spyder from the DOS prompt. I got "RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa" as was the case before. Just as I was rolling my eyes, Spyder went ahead and started. So I think it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the .condarc file. I do not know the specific reason but I faced the same issue and when I deleted the .condarc file it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error on Linux and solved deleting:

```
rm -rf .local/lib/python3.9/
rm -rf .local/share/Spyder/
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error on Windows 10 and I [found this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18066) really helpful.

In short as @ccordoba12 said "This error usually appears because you installed `pyqt5` with `pip` at some point."

Here's [the video they posted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs), and the most important thing is at 2:39 (step3), just follow the instructions in the video and delete the content under the folder `/AppData/Roaming/python`.

This approach solved my problem.